# Integration question with $e$ to the $x$ as an exponent

Tags: calculus

I was given this problem in a calculus class many years ago. The teacher didn't have the answer and I am still looking.

$$\int(1+x)^{e^x}dx$$

Comment: Are you sure you were given $\int (1+x)^{e^x} \mathrm dx$? That one ain't simple...

Comment: Wolframalpha does not know [the integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281%2Bx%29%5E%28exp%28x%29%29).

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Alpha says the following:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281%2Bx%29%5Ee%5Ex

In my opinion that integral cannot be expressed by elementary functions.

Answer (score 2):

According to Maple solution is given by expression:

$x\cdot _2F_1(1,-e^{-x};2;-x)$, where

$_2F_1(1,-e^{-x};2;-x)$ is [Hypergeometric_function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series)

Comment: Are you sure? When I differentiate your purported result, it looks nothing like the OP's integrand...

Comment: @J.M,Maple output: $x\cdot hypergeom([1,-e^x],[2],-x)$

Comment: Okay, try differentiating that result you got and see if it's the same as $(1+x)^{e^x}$.

Comment: Maple 15 does, indeed, say this.  But numerically it seems wrong.  For the integral from 0 to 1, numerical integration gets 2.482416157 but Maple's antiderivative yields 3.270804242.